# Best practice to create large hardware VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, firewall

I do have a task to connect 200 small offices to one central using hardware VPN. The server side is Dell Sonicwall NSA 3500 and the client side is DLink DSR 250n. As I dont have much experience on building such a big networks, I just did it as Ipsec-site-to-site connections just for 2 offices so far.

So, I've got a question am I on the right way? What would be the best practice to create this kind of network? Is Ipsec-site-to-site enough for this purpose?

I will run a web based app on Tomcat, the system is Windows Server 2008R2. So, everyone who will be connected to vpn, could open that web application and work with that. +Domain, +FileSharing in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about that security appliance, but IPSEC-Site-to-Site looks good to me.

If the offices access only the web based app, you might also consider to simply create firewall rules that allow traffic to the tomcat server only from the offices. That's only possible if every office has a static ip address. And the web app should have a strong auth mechanism, of course. You would not have to create VPNs, that also consume quite more bandwith than https-connections.

In the end, it depends on the hardware and the available bandwidth.